# How to query a XML with namespaces in the name?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm working with a XML like this:

```xml
<ListOfLore>
      <q1:Lore xmlns:q1="http://www.rold.com/Data.xsd">                
        <q1:LoreNumber>15642</q1:LoreNumber>        
      </q1:Lore>
      <q1:Lore xmlns:q1="http://www.rold.com/Data.xsd">
        <q1:LoreNumber>15644</q1:LoreNumber>        
      </q1:Lore>
</ListOfLore>
```

I'm doing this and I'm getting nothing

```
var lores = (from ListOfLore in pjs.Descendants("ListOfLore")
                              from Lore in ListOfLore.Descendants()
                              where Lore.Name.LocalName == ("Lore") 
                              select Lore);
```

I want to get all of `Lore` items from the `ListOfLore`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.rold.com/Data.xsd";
var lores = (from lore in pjs.Descendants(ns + "Lore")
             select lore);
```

As Jon notes, you don't need the query syntax. The following is shorter and clearer:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.rold.com/Data.xsd";
var lores = pjs.Descendants(ns + "Lore");
```

Comment: Why use a query expression at all?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I wouldn't, but that's what the OP started out with. So I went with it to not change too much. Added the "method chains" syntax as an alternative.